# How to address the path when I want to read a text file using Java, and the java file and the text file are in the same folder

Tags: java, text-files

Sorry but I am quite new to Java. 
I wanna write java code to read a text file which is in the same folder of the Java file. Can you guys give me some example codes? Many Thanks!

Comment: As a rule, you shouldn't have the file you are reading in the same folder as your Java file. Java files should be structured in packages.
See the link above for details on how to get the actual path of the running .jar file

Comment: Please clarify. Is the file in the same source package as the `.java` file? Or is it located in the bin directory with the `.jar` file?

Answer (score 1):

If java class file and text file is in same directory. See [How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file) as Christopher suggested above.

You can Read a file like below in Java :

```
package com.Test.io;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BufferedReaderExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\XYZ.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
```

See also : [best-way-to-read-a-text-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file)

Comment: Thank you! It's just what I want.